# Ember js - convert handlebar component into a string

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember CLI `1.13.8` and have a file `info.hbs`:

```
Your name is {{name}}
```

I want to convert this handlebar into a string like:

```
"<div>Your name is xxx</div>"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's not really a good way to do this. HTMLbars renders to DOM, not to a string. Can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: @GJK I want to create a google infowindow based on the `ember data` that is pushed from backend. I am customising the default infowindow and adding it some styles.

For eg: If the `payment` in the ember-data is false, then Im displaying **NOT PAID** in a red button. Else im displaying **PAID** in a green button. What is the efective way in ember to do it???

Comment: This may be helpful https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5534#issuecomment-60527838 http://jsbin.com/newub/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, but I can think of at least one way. Render your HTML to a hidden component, then grab the HTML from the DOM directly.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    style: 'display:none;',

    didRender() {
        // Do whatever you want with the HTML
        const htmlString = this.$().html();
    }
});
```

You can place this component anywhere in your app. Depending on your use case you might want to combine this component with the component that will render your infoview, or just place this in the application template and have it update some state when it changes.